# How to enable Nginx binding to UDP port 10000 with SELinux

Tags: centos, selinux, udp

Not sure if ServerFault is a better place for this question?

I'm building a new application which needs Nginx to bind to UDP port 10000. If this were a TCP port for HTTP/S then I'd just add it to the `http_port_t` port type with `semanage`, but I'm not sure what to do in this case. Is there an equivalent type for application traffic on UDP, or should I be going about this in a different way?

I'm running CentOS 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also add UDP ports in addition to existing TCP ports for a port type with semanage. For example there's already this predefined:

```
# semanage port -l |grep zebra
zebra_port_t                   tcp      2606, 2608-2609, 2600-2604
zebra_port_t                   udp      2606, 2608-2609, 2600-2604
```

So this should do it for your case

```
# semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p udp 10000
```